# Track Changes Made Through Queries in Access Database

Tags: ms-access, journaling

I'm working with an Access database and have found tools to track changes made through forms. I understand it is not possible to track changes made directly through the tables, but I've had a hard time finding out if it's possible to track changes made through SQL update statements? I'm guess it's not possible, but if anyone has thoughts on how to do it, it would be greatly appreciated. Maybe through macros?

thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can if using 2010 or later use table triggers and store procedures. This would in fact allow you to log changes made by a user updating data:

With forms,
With VBA code and recordsets,
With SQL update quires.

So an update to any row will cause the table trigger to run. I cannot say you want to write too much code, but you do have table level code that can run on an update to a row, and how that update occurs.

So a row update as an result VBA code, reocrdsets, forms, or SQL updates will case that table code to run.

As noted, you need to be running Access 2010 or later for this feature.

Comment: Great! I will look into that. I am using 2010. Thanks so much.